# pull project attached to Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, dart, aws-amplify

I face issue when i clone repo attached to AWS amplify service
I got this error

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':amplify_auth_cognito'.
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: this and base files have different roots: D:\Talents List project\build\amplify_auth_cognito and C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\amplify_auth_cognito-0.1.0\android.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

i tried those:

upgrade dependencies

flutter clean

flutter pub cache repair

none of them help me